# Write string in terminal with AppleScript

Tags: string, terminal, applescript

I would like to write in the terminal with applescript, only, for example, hello world, without enter becouse I must be able to continue writing after text... how can I proceed?

```html
tell application "Terminal"
    - Some Command for Write "Hello" -
end tell
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To execute a terminal command, try the following:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "echo 'Hello world'"
end tell
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify without sending, I must be able to continue writing after the text...

Comment: @Jimmy. Then edit your question to include all of your requirements.